# Можно ли все заголовки записать в один единый файл?

Tags: c++, архитектура, include

В любом большом проекте очень много файлов, и при создании новых приходится прописывать `include` для очень многих хедеров. Если расположение или имя какого-то файла меняется, приходится исправлять все `include-ы`. Мне в голову пришла идея - раз уж мы используем `define` или `pragma once` (кстати почему-то в описании нашего любимого микрософта [пример](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=msvc-170#include-guards) для pragma once состоит из define-ов , *есть ли между ними разница?*)для того чтобы подключить заголовок лишь один раз, так почему бы все заголовки не держать в одном файле для заголовков и везде подключать только его? Особенно удобно это может быть удобно для статических библиотек: чтобы не подключать несколько модулей по отдельности - прописал один хедер и готово! **Насколько я понимаю**(исправьте, пожалуйста, если это не так), всё равно при линковке компилятор возьмёт в бинарь только те функции, которые мы используем.
Я пока не увидел подводных камней или минусов, но опыт подсказывает: если так до сих пор никто не делает, значит стоит усомниться, помогите разобраться пожалуйста:)

Comment: Можно, В gcc есть такой. Только какой смысл при каждой компиляции перечитывать... Сейчас посмотрю... 19 мегабайт заголовочных файлов в VC++, например? (А если с заголовочными Windows Kits, то больше 300...) И не просто перечитывать, а выполнять определенные действия по компиляции. Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @Harry , Здравствуйте! Исключительно в удобстве для программиста редактирования только одного файла при изменении названий заголовков, путей к ним или подобных ситуациях

Comment: При работе в команде (даже не очень большой) всегда возникают неудобства, когда несколько человек правят один файл. Далее понятно?

Comment: Что вы собираетесь править в *заголовках стандартной библиотеки*?...

Comment: @Harry в заголовках стандартных библиотек я ничего не правлю,а в заголовках пользовательских очень даже бывает, более того часто, когда предметная область требует более детальной декомпозиции, приходится создавать новые директории и вложения, какие-то файлы теперь будут не в корне текущей директории, а , например, в своей отдельной

Comment: @avp - тут конечно согласен, есть недостаток

Comment: А пользовательские — это **полностью ваше дело**, что и как туда вносить. Нет никакого требования типа "один файл - один класс" или чего-то еще. Тут вы как хотите (если сами) или как команда решила, так и работаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"если так до сих пор никто не делает"* - почему же, это весьма распространённое явление. Причем зачастую это происходит как побочный эффект от использования прекомпилированого заголовочного файла. Однако проблем возникает куча:

- Происходит накопление ненужных инклюдов - они постоянно добавляются, но не удаляются, так как неизвестно, не требуются ли они по-прежнему в каком-то файле.
- При разделении проекта на части или переносе кода в другие проекты возникают большие сложности с пониманием того, какие заголовочные файлы и библиотеки нужны для этих частей. И некоторые просто везде таскают все подряд.
- Если это проект-библиотека, то если его заголовочные файлы не будут самодостаточными, то пользователям придется самим у себя подключать все заголовочные файлы зависимостей.
- Если заголовочные файлы не будут самодостаточными, то в этот единый заголовочный файл их придется включать в строгом порядке, который неявно задается связями между содержимым различных заголовочных файлов, а при любом изменении этих связей все будет страшно ломаться.

Answer (score 3):

Если так сделать, то при изменении любого хедера будет пересобираться весь проект - это долго.